# Remove value from hash in loop if value not in another hash

Tags: ruby, linux

I have loop which reads linux proc file and parsing utime value for running PHP processes. I store these values into hash (domain name and utime value). In the second array, I keep only domain names actually running PHP processes. What I need to do is, when there is no PHP process running for specific domain (for ex. domain had only 1 php process running in first loop run but it has finished and in the second loop run there is no more PHP processes for this domain), I want to remove this record from the hash where is stored domain name and utime. I hope it is clear enough.

I tried both of following but it not works, in the output I can still see domain for no process is running (run before, in the first loop run).

```
bla.delete_if {|key, value| not vhostnames.include?(key)}
bla.each{|k,_| bla.delete(k) if not vhostnames.include?(k)}
```

Full code is:

```
bla = {}
vhostnames = []

loop do
   # Here I find PHP processes and parse domain name of PHP process
   ....
   # This is first array when I store only domain names for PHP process is running for now
   vhostnames << vhostname

   # Here I parse content of proc file
   ...
   # Here I save or update value to hash
   if not bla.has_key?(vhostname)
            bla[vhostname] = utime_proc
   else 
            bla.each do |key,value|
                if key == vhostname
                   bla[key] = value + utime_proc
                end
            end
   end

   # Here is the place where I try to exclude value from array
   # None of these two rows works as expected
   # bla.delete_if {|key, value| not vhostnames.include?(key)}
   # bla.each{|k,_| bla.delete(k) if not vhostnames.include?(k)}

   # Here I print it out
   bla.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse.each do |k,v|
                  puts "#{k} ---> #{v}"
        end
# End loop
end
```

Comment: Your full code doesn't include the part where you delete a key from hash `bla`. Can you update it to make it look exactly like you have it on your end?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Sure, I updated the code and my post.

Comment: Btw, instead of using `not`, you can use `vhostnames.exclude?(key)`

Comment: Do one thing. Uncomment `bla.delete_if` statement and print the values of `bla` and `vhostnames` on either side of it. I can't find any issue in deleting a key-value pair from hash here.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh When I use exclude I got error `undefined method `exclude?' for #<Array:0x0055739dd0f3e8> (NoMethodError)`  I print the values and I think I found the problem. The vhostnames array is not resetting, its just growing. So, when process is still exists in second loop run to vhostnames array is new value just adding and old values from previous loop run are still our there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I just added a `vhostnames.clear` before loop end and code works fine now!

The working code for removing value from hash is this `bla.delete_if {|key, value| not vhostnames.include?(key)}`

Thank you @JagdeepSingh for help.

Comment: Or instead of `#clear`, You can simply move `vhostnames = []` to inside the `loop` as first statement.